# Can I create own auto generated code in Android Studio IDE?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, code-generation

For example: I like use next code with library retrofit. I created abstract class and use it for simplify create retrofit API interface implementation.
Can I add this code in Android Studio(or IDEA) and use autogenerate when I need?

```
public abstract class AnyApiBuilder<T> {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 20;

    public abstract T build();

    protected T build(Class<T> api) {
        return build(api, ServerUri.MAIN_SERVER_URI);
    }

    protected T build(Class<T> api, String uri) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(uri)
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build()
                .create(api);
    }

}
```

and

```
public interface GetAppsApi {

    @POST("/get_apps")
    void getApps(@Body GetAppsRequest request, Callback<GetAppsResponse> callback);

    class Builder extends AnyApiBuilder<GetAppsApi> {
        public GetAppsApi build() {
            return build(GetAppsApi.class);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the code and go to Tools->"Save as Live Template"

You can then set abbreviation, description and variables.

The abbreviation is what you type to generate the code followed by a `Tab`.

[image]